# Updating MGTwitterEngine to New Twitter API v1.1

Tags: iphone, cookies, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I am currently updating my app to .json from xml for Twitters new API v1.1. I currently have .json working and can log on, get me timelines, mentions, but when trying to get direct messages, lists, or user info it seems its looking for "cookies" but it is not stored.

This is the error message received by twitter when trying to make a simple GET user/show call:

```
Twitter request failed: 08AD12D3-0044-49AB-8D3D-4E61D8398550 with error:Error Domain=HTTP 
 Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 400.)" UserInfo=0xce90540  
{response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xce94bd0> { URL: 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=FreeAppl3 } { status code: 400,  
headers {
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Fri, 14 Jun 2013 09:25:40 UTC";
Server = tfe;
"Set-Cookie" = "guest_id=v1%3A137120194019582695; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; 
Expires=Sun, 14-Jun-2015 09:25:40 UTC";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=631138519";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;

} }, body={"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}hjD4nzoeOUaTQ1Q%3D}
```

When I call [twitterEngine isAuthorized]; is returns YES and if I check for my access token string, I receive  what was stored on initial login. I have searched and searched as to what is happening or how to fix the issues, but am simply stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Twitter API - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show
Twitter Error Codes - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer   [FHSTwitterEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081012/how-to-get-user-details-using-twitter-api-v1-1-twitter-error-215/17083649#17083649) you can use newly  FHSTwitterEngine and if you request this method without autenticating, the users status is removed... you need to send consumer key and token along with screen_name..

In FHSTwitterEngine

```
//get username pass to method. In Dictionary you can get all info  
NSString *username = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loggedInUsername];
NSDictionary *data=[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]getUserProfile:username];


 // method to get all user info
-(id)getUserProfile:(NSString *)username
{

   if (username.length == 0) {
      return getBadRequestError();
   }

   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url_users_show];
   OAMutableURLRequest *request = [OAMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL consumer:self.consumer token:self.accessToken];
   OARequestParameter *usernameP = [OARequestParameter requestParameterWithName:@"screen_name" value:username];

   NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:usernameP, nil];

   id userShowReturn = [self sendGETRequest:request withParameters:params];
   return userShowReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this before but wasnt sure if going with a whole new engine would help. At second glance this is a much better engine and is already ready for version 1.1