# How to get all user information from twitter with api v1.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am making an app in which I want to show twitter login user's image and name. I ma able to get the all information in api 1.0 of twitter but now when I call again this then it gives an error "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.
[twitter api overview](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview)" So can you suggest any code or link where I can get all information of users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link  [FHSTwitterEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103831/updating-mgtwitterengine-to-new-twitter-api-v1-1/17107826#17107826) and check the code given in answer.. FHSTwitterEngine is latest library with compatible with v1.1.. its should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this library. [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine)

It uses twitter api 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But It is not working properly on iOS 5.0

Comment: It runs fine on iOS 6.1. But I haven't tried to run it on iOS 5.0. what problem are u having ?