# How to modify Twitter API v1.0 to v1.1 in Detweetcomposeviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter, social-networking

I am using below mentioned third party twitter Control .

And recently twitter changed API `v1.0` t0 `v1.1`
and how to change those modification in this control.

[DETweetComposeViewController for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/detweetcomposeviewcontroller)

Any help really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just change 1 to 1.1 like `NSString * const twitterPostURLString = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
NSString * const twitterPostWithImagesURLString = @"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json";` in DETweetPoster.m class

Comment: Thanks for replying.I changed those things,but tweet failed. could you guide me?

Comment: check the `setAccount:` property has been used or not for TWRequest, and check the `ACAccount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17083649/1091539) will help you about the new `Twitter API`

Its very much satisfied and relieved.. its working for me.