# migrate to twitter v1.1 from 1.0 in ios

Tags: ios, twitter

I have used the **Twitter+OAuth** in my application . Successfully I have logged into the twitter ( It is giving message in the log as **authenticated for username** ) . But When I click on the post me button (I am trying to post message in my twitter account) it is saying that `Http 410 error operation couldn't be completed` . I have been searching for this issue since yesterday . Can anyone please help me how to migrate to v1.1 . And another issue is when I can the Request URI in the Twitter account it is not saving . Please tell me how to solve these issues .Thanks in advance .

Comment: you need to pass credentials at every request from v1.1. Are you sending at time of posting message?

Comment: refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081012/how-to-get-user-details-using-twitter-api-v1-1-twitter-error-215/17083649#17083649)

Comment: Thanks for the link @the1pawan but It is not worked for me because I have used the Twitter +OAuth library .

Comment: If there is any example please send me some link

Comment: If any one have any issues please let me know guys . I have resolved it after a long search .