# Is there any library to implement twitter web view login dialog in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication

i have an app that want to share to twitter

when user click the share button and he has a token the app will process in the background and tweet using predefined message (user cannot change the message)

but if he/she doesn't have the token then the app will show popup login webview dialog 
to the user with our app name like in the picture.

After he/she successfully login dismiss login dialog and the app will repeat step 1 (tweet in background)

[image]

how can i archive this?
thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer [FHSTwitterEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081012/how-to-get-user-details-using-twitter-api-v1-1-twitter-error-215/17083649#17083649)you can use newly FHSTwitterEngine  you need to send consumer key and token along with screen_name..

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is to implement the Single Sign on (SSO) using native App residing on Device. Almost all the Social Framework SKD's are approaching to use the account information residing centrally on the device. (That's called as SSO via Native)

Please read more about it [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios)

Also if you face difficulty in implementing it, kindly use [shareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) or [PFTwitterUtils-NativeTwitter](https://github.com/FuturaIO/PFTwitterUtils-NativeTwitter).

In ShareKit, you many need to perform a "Granular Install" to just link to "Twitter" library rather than all other bunch of Social Frameworks.