# iOS: Twitter update profile api giving error

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am trying to access update profile api of twitter. But its giving error.

```
let conn = WebserviceConnectionManager(serviceTokenId: "Twitter profile")

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile.json")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let oAuthToken = FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine().accessToken.key
        let oAuthTokenSecret = FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine().accessToken.secret

        request.addValue(oAuthToken, forHTTPHeaderField:"oauth_token")
        request.addValue(oAuthTokenSecret, forHTTPHeaderField:"oauth_token_secret")

        conn.delegate = self
        conn.startConnection(request)
```

Callback method gives me following error:

```
errors =     (
            {
        code = 215;
        message = "Bad Authentication data.";
    }
);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since Twitter's API 1.1 does not allow access without authentication, because you have to use access tokens and secret keys; all requests must be made with a server-side script. 
follow steps [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth) and you will fixed  your problem.

Comment: I am doing the authentication using FHSTwitterEngine. After successful login, I am calling the rest API.

Comment: @TechBee check it please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081012/how-to-get-user-details-using-twitter-api-v1-1-twitter-error-215